# Unable to login using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to customize spring security Login mechanism implemented in an existing spring mvc application. this is the entry from spring security xml file

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/my-account" always-use-
default-target="false" authentication-failure-handler-ref="failureHandler" 
authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler" />
```

this was working fine since when ever user want to login he/she was being redirected to the login page who was having a URL like

```
www.myapp.com/login
```

as per new requirement we have to impalement one global Login panel which will be there throughout the application and user can Login from there, at same time there will be some cases when user trying to access a secure area will be redirected to Login page and in that case URL can be like

```
www.myapp.com/login/
```

being new to spring security i am not sure how should i handle this use-case should i change the `login-page="/login"` to `login-page="/*"`
any pointer in this regard will really be helpful

**Edit**

i saw following entry in my spring-security xml file

```
<bean id="mainAuthEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        scope="tenant">
        <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login" />
        <property name="forceHttps" value="true" />
        <property name="useForward" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

now it made me more confused as where all i need to change if any

Comment: It is not clear what you want. What do you mean by "global"? It could happen that you just want to display a login page each time user try to access to some secure area?

Comment: by `global` i mean, there will be a login pannel on the header section of website and when user click on Login button a pop-up/overlay will open in same screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds like you want an iframe or ajax authentication method.

This article may be a good starting point for you to look into:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/implementing-ajax